# Why MySQL Server shutdown after getting some hits

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My website attracts more than 40 thousands unique visitors daily. When it gets 50 visitors simultaneously, sometimes the mySQL server shutdown itself and it gives error: "mysql cannot connect to database server"

the website on vps: its ram is 2 gb.

Is this due to low ram or low ranking features of vps?

When I restart the mySQL server, the problem is resolved.

The website is using wordpress as cms.

If there are some like me facing this issue and not know how they restart the mysql server, here it is: first login your whm and search MySQL, youll see restart MySQl button, click on it. http://www.saderesim.com/SxueS30

Comment: done any basic debugging, like looking at mysql logs to see WHY it's shutting down? And this isn't really a programming issue. This is server administration.

Comment: Based on the few morsels of information you've provided, the most likely cause is that both the MySQL instance and a Linux host its running on are *very* badly configured and the DBMS is being taken out by the OOM killer. All of which would be detailled in the logs - please go read them. But it could also also be hundreds of other things. Gather some data. Read your logs. If yo'e still stuck, have a look at some of the Q&A here, noting what gets downvoted and closed and what gets upvoted and answered.

Comment: The problem is, I dont know how to reach the logs regarding mysql that you are talking about. can i have these through WHM?